# Delete and recreate WriteStream

Tags: node.js

In Node.js how can you delete the file a `WriteStream` was writing to and then recreate the stream without error?

With this code

```js
    clear(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.stream.once('close', () => {
                Fs.unlinkSync(this.filepath);
                this.stream = Fs.createWriteStream(this.filepath, {flags: 'a'});
                resolve();
            });
            this.stream.end();
        });
    }
```

This error occurs. I've tried everything.

`Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\test\test.log'`

---

The calling code

```
it('erases the log file', async () => {
    const file = new File("C:\test\test.log");
    await file.clear();
    const exists = Fs.existsSync(testfile);
    Assert.strictEqual(exists, false);
});
```

I can only avoid the error if I remove the `this.stream = Fs.createWriteStream(this.filepath, {flags: 'a'});` in `clear()`

Comment: The code you provide does not provide a reproducible case.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When I try to duplicate your issue here, I only get that error if you are not properly waiting for the `clear()` method to finish before you attempt to use the stream again.

For example, this code works:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class MyFile {
    constructor(filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
        this.open();
    }
    open() {
        this.stream = fs.createWriteStream(this.filepath, { flags: 'a' });
        this.stream.on('error', err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    log(str) {
        this.stream.write(str);
    }
    clear() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.stream.once('close', () => {
                console.log("got clear close event");
                try {
                    fs.unlinkSync(this.filepath);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                this.open();
                resolve();
            });
            this.stream.end();
        });
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.stream.once('close', () => {
                console.log("got final close event");
                resolve();
            });
            this.stream.end();
        });
    }
}

async function run() {
    const f = new MyFile("./temp.xxx");
    f.log("hello\n");
    f.log("goodbye\n");
    await f.clear();
    f.log("hello\n");
    f.log("goodbye\n");
    await f.close();
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But, if I remove the `await` in front of `await f.clear()`, then I get your exact error because the code proceeds trying to use the stream after you've called `this.stream.end()`, but before the new stream is in place which is an EPERM error.

If this doesn't illustrate for you what your problem is, then you need to show us all the rest of the code that uses this class and calls the `clear()` method.  The problem is likely in that code.

Comment: The calling code is a mocha test. I do use `async` and I do `await`, and in fact nothing happens after the test. I am perplexed.

Comment: @pbuzz007 - Show the code for a reproducible case and we can help you be less perplexed.

Comment: Updated.          Not much to see

Comment: @pbuzz007 - The code you provide in your question does not provide a reproducible case.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You are apparently doing something different in your implementation than in my implementation - thus causing your error.  Can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: I am able to reproduce with your code. In your function `run`, if you re-create the `MyFile` before the `await f.clear()` then it produces the same `operation not permitted` error. My guess is the fd is still open or something. And with no destructor, I guess there is no way to fix this.

Comment: @pbuzz007 - There's absolutely a way to fix it using events on the stream.   If you show me your ACTUAL code, I can probably offer you a fix.  Why, why, why  do you not show your actual code?  Baffles me to no end.  Can't fix code we can't see.  You will notice that my implementation does NOT have the problem you have because I'm managing the stream state appropriately.